# WCF service to AppFabric

Tags: wcf, appfabric

I have a WCF service that we created. Are there any steps that you need to do to convert it to be able to run on AppFabric? In the past when I have created services for AppFabric I have used the AppFabric Item type in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. You need to install App Fabric on IIS, and you can configure anything there. Nothing special needs to be done on the C#/WCF side. However, you are able to adjust the config file of your project to alter the App Fabric settings, just as you would for IIS.